# Python parent class modifiable by child class or dynamic attribute?

Tags: python

So I am not even sure if what I want to do is possible but I thought I would ask and find out.

I want to build a chef "databag" via python. This is pretty much just a python dictionary. There are other things that need to happen with this databag that are encapsulated in the Databag class.

Now for the meat of the question...
I want to add key/values to this dictionary but need to build it in a way that is easily extensible. NOTE: the `autodict` is a class that makes it so you can build a dictionary using dot notation.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
databag = Databag(
  LogGroup=Sub("xva-${environment}-${uniqueid}-mygroup"),
  RunList=[
    "mysetup::default",
    "consul::client"
  ]
)
databag.Consul()  <-- Trying to add consul key/values to databag
print(databag.to_dict())
print(databag.to_string_list())
```

So you can see how I add the "consul" key values to the already existing databag object.

Here are the class definitions. I know this is wrong which is why I am here to see if this is even possible.

`Databag Class`

```
class Databag(object):

def __init__(self,uniqueid=Ref("uniqueid"),environment=Ref("environment"),LogGroup=None,RunList=[]):
    self.databag = autodict()
    self.databag.uniqueid = uniqueid
    self.databag.environment = environment
    self.databag.log.group = LogGroup
    self.runlist=RunList

def to_string_list(self):
    return self.convert_databag_to_string(self.databag)

def to_dict(self):
    return self.databag

def get_runlist(self):
    return self.convert_to_runlist_string(self.runlist)
```

`Consul Class`

```
class Consul(Databag):

  def __init__(self, LogGroup=None):
      if LogGroup == None:
          Databag.consul.log.group = Databag.log.group
      else:
          Databag.consul.log.group = LogGroup
```

As you can see the `Consul` class is supposed to access the `databag` dictionary of the `Databag` class and add the "consul" variables, almost like an attribute. However, I don't want to add a new function to the databag class every time otherwise that class will end up being very, very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something like this to work with the following method. Although I am up for an suggestions to get this to work. I just read the help posted on this link:

http://www.qtrac.eu/pyclassmulti.html

**EDIT**: This method is a lot easier:

Note: This uses the exact same implementation of the old method.

`consul.py`

```
from classes.databag.utils import *

class Consul:
    def Consul(self, LogGroup=None):
        if LogGroup == None:
            self.databag.consul.log.group = self.databag.log.group
        else:
            self.databag.consul.log.group = LogGroup
```

`databag.py`

```
from classes.databag.utils import autodict
from classes.databag import consul

class Databag(consul.Consul):

    def __init__(self,uniqueid=Ref("uniqueid"),environment=Ref("environment"),LogGroup=None,RunList=[]):
        self.databag = autodict()
        self.databag.uniqueid = uniqueid
...
...
```

`Folder Structure`

```
/classes/
    databag/
        utils.py
        databag.py
        consul.py
testing.py
```

---

### ---- OLD METHOD -----

`How I implemented it`

```
from classes.databag.databag import *

databag = Databag(
    LogGroup=Sub("xva-${environment}-${uniqueid}-traefik"),
    RunList=[
        "mysetup::default",
        "consul::client"
    ]
)
databag.Consul()

print(databag.to_dict())
print(databag.to_string_list())
```

`lib.py`

```
def add_methods_from(*modules):
    def decorator(Class):
       for module in modules:
           for method in getattr(module, "__methods__"):
               setattr(Class, method.__name__, method)
       return Class
return decorator

def register_method(methods):
    def register_method(method):
        methods.append(method)
        return method
    return register_method
```

`databay.py`

```
from classes.databag import lib, consul

@lib.add_methods_from(consul)
class Databag(object):

    def __init__(self,uniqueid=Ref("uniqueid"),environment=Ref("environment"),LogGroup=None,RunList=[]):
        self.databag = autodict()
        self.databag.uniqueid = uniqueid
    ....
    ....
```

`consul.py`

```
from classes.databag import lib

__methods__ = []
register_method = lib.register_method(__methods__)

@register_method
def Consul(self, LogGroup=None):
    if LogGroup == None:
        self.databag.consul.log.group = self.databag.log.group
    else:
        self.databag.consul.log.group = LogGroup
```

`Folder Structure`

```
/classes/
    /databag
        lib.py
        databag.py
        consul.py
        utils.py
/testing.py
```